# xml file in android studio appears an error

Tags: android, android-studio

i am following [This Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/) but when try to copy or even write the same code of header_gradient.xml which is

```
header_gradient.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#24b2eb"
        android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
        android:endColor="#24b2eb"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

in blank xml file it shows an error, does android studio support to create blank xml file? or is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: that error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638904/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-screensprocessdebugresources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tgrll thanks for your answer in response to my both question my code is correct but little edition only need to add --android:layout_width="50" android:layout_height="50"-- in the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:layout_width="50" android:layout_height="50">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#24b2eb"
            android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
            android:endColor="#24b2eb"
            android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I use this params in element where I use shape object.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code can helps you. 
Take care on android:shape="rectangle" .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:centerColor="@color/Bisque"
    android:endColor="@color/Red"
    android:startColor="@color/Red" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="@color/Black" />

<corners android:radius="3dip" />

<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Try this for your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#24b2eb"
        android:centerColor="#4ccbff"
        android:endColor="#24b2eb"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: thanks but its shown an error too here is the error detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638904/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-screensprocessdebugresources